# Can i get maven dependency of Capybara?

Tags: java, maven, capybara

I have one rails application. Right now i am using

> Parallel_test

gem with Capybara, Cucumber testing framework. Now i am trying to use

> Cucumber-JVM

Since previously i have written all my scenario steps in Capybara, so is there any maven dependency of capybara? So that i can use that in my pom file and use existing capybara steps as it is in

> Cucumbr-JVM

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't because there is no port of Capybara to Java. But you can always write your tests in `Ruby` and than run them from some other Java project. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164593/is-it-possible-to-test-java-application-with-capybara) post explains how to do that.